4x4 banded matrix inverse
Let $a,b,c$ be reals such that $ab-c^2\neq0$, and let
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} a & 0 & c & 0 \\ 0 & a & 0 & c \\ c & 0 & b & 0 \\ 0 & c & 0 & b \end{pmatrix}.
$$
The matrix inverse is
$$
A^{-1} = \frac1{ab-c^2}\begin{pmatrix} b & 0 & -c & 0 \\ 0 & b & 0 & -c \\ -c & 0 & a & 0 \\ 0 & -c & 0 & a \end{pmatrix}.
$$
This very curiously (in my opinion) resembles the formula of the $2\times 2$ inverse matrix applied to the $2 \times 2$ diagonal blocks composing the matrix.
What's the rule I'm not seeing?

You can get this immediately via abuse of notation:
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} a & 0 & c & 0 \\ 0 & a & 0 & c \\ c & 0 & b & 0 \\ 0 & c & 0 & b \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a  & c  \\ c  & b \end{pmatrix}
$$
Now you have a $2\times 2$ matrix and can apply the usual formula.
If you want it a bit more formal, use $A= \begin{pmatrix}a & c \\ c & b\end{pmatrix} \otimes \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\left( M \otimes N \right)^{-1} = M^{-1} \otimes N^{-1}$
